# VB.NET: Pointer and Address Operator from C / Convert C to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pointers, address-operator

```
double *dDevTabPressure;
static double sPT_Mach;
dDevTabPressure = &sPT_Mach;
```

I want to convert this C-code  to VB.NET-code. Unfortunatly there are no pointer and adress operator in VB.NET 
Do you have a simple soloution?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're going to need more context (specifically code) to be able to help you. For instance: Where and how are these variables used later on? Depending on the code, you might not have to convert all of it into .NET. You could also compile it into a C/C++ DLL and P/Invoke that from VB.NET.

Comment: After seeing the code I definitely think you would be much better of compiling this into a DLL (if it isn't already) and instead P/Invoke that from VB.NET. Converting C/C++ to VB.NET is usually more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While VB.NET doesn't have pointers, you can use an object to wrap the Double.  Object assignments (=) are by reference instead of by value like simple data types.

For example, this sample code wraps the double into an anonymous object.  This when the value is updated in one object, its updated in the other because the object points to the same location in memory.

```
    Dim devTabPressure = New With {.Value = Convert.ToDouble(2)}
    Dim devTabPressure2 = devTabPressure
    devTabPressure.Value = 5

    Console.WriteLine(devTabPressure.Value) ' Writes a 5
    Console.WriteLine(devTabPressure2.Value)  ' ALSO Writes a 5
    Console.Read()
```